# Difference between "there is sth between them" and "they have sth between them"

Tags: meaning, tenses, sentence

Is there any difference in meanings of the following two sentences?

> They have a secret tunnel between them.
>
> There is a secret tunnel between them.

Comment: 'There is ...' sounds more clinical / impersonal and might be considered the preferred style here.

Comment: I fail to see how two people can **have a secret tunnel between them**, regardless of how it is expressed.

Comment: So, the question is inadequate.  The OP needs to explain who "they" are.  Are they people or buildings or cities or what?

Answer (score 2):

Seems to me it's a difference in ownership.

> They have a secret tunnel between them.

Whoever "they" are, they own/built/are responsible for/use a tunnel.  As in, "Bob lives in that house and Joe lives in that other house; they have a secret tunnel between them."  (Bob and Joe are best buds and hang out all the time together.)

> There is a secret tunnel between them.

There is no implication of ownership, just a statement of fact.  As in, "That is Bob's house and that is Joe's house and there is a secret tunnel between them."  (But Bob and Joe don't necessarily know about it.)